# How to create sub-taxonomies?

Tags: wordpress

I should have some taxonomies like below.
Taxonomies map:

```
Main taxonomy( hierarchical )
|
|----------> sub taxonomy 1 ( hierarchical )
|
|----------> sub taxonomy 2 ( hierarchical )
|
|----------> sub taxonomy 3 ( hierarchical )
|
|----------> sub taxonomy 4 ( hierarchical )
```

I create Main taxonomy:
http://www.example.com/main-taxonomy

but can't connect sub taxonomies to main taxonomy like this:
http://www.example.com/main-taxonomy/sub-taxonomy-1

I'm really confused and from 2 days I'm fighting with the sub taxonomies.

How to create sub-taxonomies ?

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to create a custom post type, apply your main taxonomy to post type, then in the admin panel go to taxonomy page(where you are creating the taxonomy), and during adding new taxonomy , make one of created taxonomies as parent for the adding one?

Comment: Yes, but how can I call term's children and parents in a custom post type?

Comment: @h4m3d99 use these two functions `get_post_taxonomies` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_taxonomies and `wp_get_post_terms` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child of the taxonomy is term, you can create with this function.

```
<?php wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. one more question, How can I insert a taxonomy, under another taxonomy? I'm more focused on taxonomies url. Something like this: www.example.com/taxonomy/another-taxonomy( not term )

Comment: I hope you are asking about the sub-page. If you create a page, the url for the page will be like `www.example.com/parent` if you create a page and make `parent` page as this page's parent, you will get `www.example.com/parent/child`